# Representation of multi-variable functions as a composition of 1- or 2-variable functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

*This is a re-post of [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1340378/19661) from M.SE that remains unanswered for several months.*

I'm familiar with [Kolmogorov–Arnold representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem), but AFAIK their construction makes essential use of non-smooth functions. I am interested in what happens if we add the smoothness requirement.

There are some well-known special functions of 3 or more complex variables that are analytic in some domain (a region in $\mathbb C^n$) with respect to each variable. To give some examples: the [incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $B(z; a, b)$, the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) $\Phi(z, s, a)$, the [Weierstrass elliptic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassEllipticFunction.html) $\wp(z;g_2,g_3)$, hypergeometric-family functions, etc. Let's restrict their domain to reals.

It is possible to express all or some of these functions as a composition of several [infinitely differentiable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-InfinityFunction.html) (with respect to each variable) functions of 1 or 2 real variables?

A similar question applies to functions of 2 variables (e.g. polylogarithms, incomplete elliptic integrals, Hurwitz zeta function, Bessel-family functions, etc.): Is it possible to represent them as a composition of several infinitely differentiable functions of 1 variable and the single fixed function of 2 variables $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$?

To give an example when the answer to the last question is positive, consider the [complete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) $B(a,b)$. It can be represented as
$$B(a,b)=\exp\big[(\ln\Gamma(a)+\ln\Gamma(b))+(-\ln\Gamma(a+b))\big]$$
that is a composition of the 2-variable sum function and several infinitely differentiable 1-variable functions $x\mapsto\exp(x)$, $x\mapsto\ln\Gamma(x)$ and $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: Did you see the answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140859/kolmogorov-superposition-for-smooth-functions and read the corresponding papers of Vitushkin (from 1954 and 1964)? In principle, it is known that for smooth functions the problem gets much harder.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Thanks, I looked exactly for that answer.