# Continuous functions of three variables as superpositions of two variable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Could we always locally represent a continuous function $F(x,y,z)$ in the form of $g\left(f(x,y),z\right)$ for suitable continuous functions $f$, $g$ of two variables? I am aware of Vladimir Arnold's [work](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-01742-1_6) on this problem, but it seems that in that context $F(x,y,z)$ is written as a sum of several expressions of this form. Can one reduce it to just a single superposition $g\left(f(x,y),z\right)$; or does anyone know a counter example?

For related posts see:

[Is there any continuous ternary function which can not be represented by composition of continuous binary functions?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/325502/121665)

[Kolmogorov superposition for smooth functions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/140859/121665)

[Kolmogorov-Arnold theorem for (just-)functions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/278868/121665)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> **Proposition.** The function $F(x,y,z)=x(1-z)+yz$ cannot be represented as $F(x,y,z)=g(f(x,y),z)$, where $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous.

**Proof.** Suppose to the contrary that we have such a representation. Let $g_1(t)=g(t,0)$. Then 
$$
g_1(f(x,y))=g(f(x,y),0)=F(x,y,0)=x.
$$ 
Let $g_2(t)=g(t,1)$. Then 
$$
g_2(f(x,y))=g(f(x,y),1)=F(x,y,1)=y.
$$
Let $h=(g_1,g_2):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $h(t)=(g_1(t),g_2(t))$. Then
$$
(h\circ f)(x,y)=(g_1(f(x,y)),g_2(f(x,y)))=(x,y).
$$
In particular, it implies that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is one-to-one.

It remains to show there there are no one-to-one continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose to the contrary that such a function $f$ exists. Let $\mathbb{S}^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit circle. Then
$$
f|_{\mathbb{S}^1}:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{R}
$$
is continuous and one-to-one. Since $\mathbb{S}^1$ is compact, $f|_{\mathbb{S}^1}$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{S}^1$ onto $f(\mathbb{S}^1)$.

Since $\mathbb{S}^1$ is connected and compact $f(\mathbb{S}^1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is connected and compact. Therefore it is a closed interval, $f(\mathbb{S}^1)=[a,b]$ and we arrive to a contradiction, because $[a,b]$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$ (to see this observe that removing an interior point from $[a,b]$ makes the space disconnected while if we remove a point form $\mathbb{S}^1$, the space will remain connected).

**Remark.** For a statement and a proof of the Kolmogorov theorem, see for example:

**G. G. Lorentz**, *Approximation of functions,* 1966.

**Edit.** I modified my original answer that was not fully correct. A mistake was pointed out by  Aleksei Kulikov in his comment. The correction is related to the arguments in the comments of KhashF and  user44191.

Comment: Thanks Piotr! But how did you deduce that $f$ has derivative? Does your example work in the continuous setting as well?

Comment: Partial derivatives aren't necessary for this proof; if you let $c = f(0, 0)$, you get that $f(x, y) = g_1^{-1}(x) = f(x, 0) = g_2^{-1}(0) = f(0, 0) = c$.

Comment: @user44191 Thank you. I modified my answer.

Comment: @KhashF I modified my answer.

Comment: I’m sorry but where you used continuity of $f$ and $g$? Because without it answer to question in OP is that every function can be represented in such a manner (via bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$). And also what is $g_1^{-1}(x)$ really? I see no reasons for $g_1$ to be injective.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov **Very good point.** However, under the continuity assumption my proof works. The continuity assumption is used implicitly and I will explain how. I will add details tomorrow.

Comment: If I may; $f(\cdot,y):x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous injective, so it must be open. Note also that if f(0,y)=f(x,0), then in fact x=0. By considering the clopen set $f(0,\cdot)^{-1}(\{f(0,0)\})=\{y:f(0,y)=f(0,0)\}=\{y:\exists x,f(0,y)=f(x,0)\}=f(0,\cdot)^{-1}(f(\mathbb R,0))$, we see that f is constant with respect to $y$, and the symmetrical argument shows that it is constant with respect to $x$.

Comment: (Sorry about the LaTeX on two lines...)

Comment: I think the implicit point in Piotr's solution where the continuity indeed plays a rule is how to get from $g_1(f(x,y))=x$ or $g_2(f(x,y))=y$ to $g_1^{-1}(x)=f(x,y)$ or $g_2^{-1}(y)=f(x,y)$: If you want to use these identities to argue that $g_1$  (resp. $g_2$) is injective, you have to show that for a fixed $y$ (resp. x) every number can be written as $f(x,y)$. This of course fails for (trivially non-continuous) bijections $f:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$. Therefore, you need an argument like Pierre's.

Comment: P.S. I think even the following works: $g_1(f(x,y))=x$, $g_2(f(x,y))=y$ imply that the continuous $f:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ is injective, a contradiction.

Comment: @KhashF I am busy now, but I will add details to my solution later so it will be clear and correct.

Comment: As an alternative approach, $h(t) := (g_1(t), g_2(t))$ is a continuous inverse to the continuous function $f(x, y)$, and therefore a homeomorphism. This approach should work category-theoretically: you can construct such functions $f, g$ on $X^2$ only if $X \simeq X^2$ in whichever category you've chosen - and since $\mathbb{R} \not \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ topologically, we're done.

Comment: It should be noted that there are non continuous functions f and g for this example, which depend on f "encoding" two reals into one and g using the decoding inverses to f to represent F.  Gerhard "Enhancing The Continuity Of Explication" Paseman, 2019.02.13.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman It has already been pointed out by  Aleksei Kulikov in his comment. I need to edit my answer and I will do it, but I am too busy in the next two weeks.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Not to pressure you, but two weeks have passed, and the argument is still missing something; I think my latest comment above provides a solution (and allows an answer to a partial generalization of the question). Are you planning to finish the answer, and if not, would you mind if I edited my idea into your answer?

Comment: @user44191 I modified my answer. Thank you for reminding me of my unfinished chore.

Comment: It is maybe a bit confusing that $g$ is used for two different functions...

Comment: Notice that the OP asked about **local** representation. But this proof still works with minor changes: replace $0$ and $1$ with $z_0\ne z_1$ and still get a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, then use any small circle in place of $S^1$.

Comment: I agree with Pietor Majer about the two $g$s being confusing. Also it seems that user44191 proposed the notation $h$ for the second $g$ in the comments. Can you please use that notation in the answer as well?

Comment: @Vincent Corrected. Is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, thank you! BTW I really like this answer.