# Is there any continuous ternary function which can not be represented by composition of continuous binary functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : X^3 \rightarrow X$.

If $X$ is $\mathbb Z$, then there will be a couple of functions $g,h$ from $\mathbb Z^2$ to $\mathbb Z$ that satisfies $f(x,y,z) = g(h(x,y),z)$ since there is a bijection $h :\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow \mathbb Z$.

However, If $X$ is $\mathbb R$, then there are no continuous bijection from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$.

My question is : Is there any continuous function $f : \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that can't be represented by composition of continuous functions $g_i : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$?
And similar questions for $f : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Sorry, I'm not sure about my tags.

Comment: Related, I think: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322184

Comment: @PierrePC Thanks! Kolmogorov superposition theorem was the answer!

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by Pierre PC in his comment, the answer follows from the **Kolmogorov** theorem. Just for a record let us state one of the version of the theorem due to **Lorentz** (there are many other more refined versions; the reader will not have difficulties to find the references).

> **Theorem.** There exist constants $0<\lambda_p\leq 1$, $1\leq p\leq n$ and strictly increasing functions $\phi_q:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, $0\leq q\leq 2n$ such that
>   if $f:[0,1]^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there is another continuous function $g:[0,n]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$
> f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{q=0}^{2n}
>  g\left(\lambda_1\phi_q(x_1)+\ldots+\lambda_n\phi_q(x_n)\right).
> $$

It is very surprising that neither the functions $\phi_q$ nor the constants $\lambda_p$ depend on $f$.

For a proof see pages 168-174  in

**G. G. Lorentz**, *Approximation of functions*, 1966.

Comment: Just to clarify, the answer is negative, since OP asked whether there existed $f$ that could *not* be expressed as $g(h(-,-),-)$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  Corrected. Thank you!

Comment: Would you please add some details on how exactly this theorem leads to the negative answer to the OP? I have an impression that the answer is negative just because you have constructed (in the linked post) an explicit counterexample.

And one more question: this variant of the Kolmogorov theorem looks a bit different from the one on Wikipedia (where $\phi_q$ depends also on $q$ and are not claimed to be increasing). Could you add some reference to the variant you provided?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description! However, the notation of index of $\phi$ is wrong at least 1 place.

Comment: @SoonwonMoon I modified my answer. I think it is more clear now.

Comment: @Skeeve  I modified my answer. I think it is more clear now.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz thanks a lot for the reference! So the functions $\phi_q$ are even Lipschitz... very interesting! But I'm still a bit mislead by the sentence `the answer follows from the Kolmogorov theorem`.

Comment: @Skeeve "represented by composition of continuous functions" is a vague statement since it does not specify what sort of representation we have in mind. But the author of the question said "Kolmogorov superposition theorem was the answer!" so the answer indeed follows from the Kolmogorov theorem.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz now I see why you chose this interpretation. Instead I was looking at the equation $f(x,y,z) = g(h(x,y),z)$ in the OP. Anyway, the picture is clear now!